# this.props.videos.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to write the elements of the array of videos to an h5 tag as follows. It print's to the console the array twice and then says this.props.videos.map is not a function. Two questions why is the array printed twice and why is it not a function after the third time? Is the map going through the array an extra time?

**Console Log**

```
It's null
Explore.js:16 {video: Array(2)}video: Array(2)0: {filter: Array(0), _id: "5b4e2df021b7b40dcb219ed6", description: "ITS ALIVE", key: "orIV61wadyQ", owner: "Death Star", …}1: {filter: Array(0), _id: "5b4e2dff21b7b40dcb219ed7", description: "ITS ALIVE AGAIN", key: "orIV61wadyQ", owner: "Death Star", …}length: 2__proto__: Array(0)__proto__: Object
Explore.js:16 {video: Array(2)}video: (2) [{…}, {…}]__proto__: Object
Explore.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.videos.map is not a function
```

**JS file**

```
class Explore extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getVideos();
  }
  render() {
    if (this.props.videos == null) {
      console.log("It's null");
    } else {
      console.log(this.props.videos);
      const videos = this.props.videos.map(video => <h5>video</h5>);
      return <div>{videos}</div>;
    }
    return <div />;
  }
}
Explore.propTypes = {
  getVideos: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  videos: PropTypes.object
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  profile: state.profile,
  auth: state.auth,
  videos: state.videos.videos
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getVideos }
)(Explore);
```

Comment: Your object's key is 'video', not 'videos'.

Comment: It's called two times because React renders another time your component, since the props have changed (that's why you don't see the same thing twice in the two console.log). And from what is logged, you should try `this.props.videos.video` to see if it is not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two comments for you:

1) You should use the properties you want inside the map function cause you call print the whole object

```
 const videos = this.props.videos.map(video => <h5>{video._id}</h5>);
```

2) set defaultProps e.g:

```
class Explore extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getVideos();
  }
  render() {
    if (this.props.videos == null) {
      console.log("It's null");
    } else {
      console.log(this.props.videos);
      const videos = this.props.videos.map(video => <h5>video</h5>);
      return <div>{videos}</div>;
    }
    return <div />;
  }
}
Explore.defaultProps = {
    videos: []
}
Explore.propTypes = {
  getVideos: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  videos: PropTypes.object
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  profile: state.profile,
  auth: state.auth,
  videos: state.videos.videos
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getVideos }
)(Explore);
```

Comment: I added "this.props.videos.video.map" with your suggestion and it worked...redux...

Comment: @The_Enigma glad to hear! Enjoy :)